# Looping through two views to check for equality

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view

I have two identical views with a number of editTexts. In one, pre-defined answers are populated in the editTexts (but not shown to the user). In the second, the user starts with all blank editTexts, and then fills them out in an attempt to make them the same as the pre-defined answers.

So I want to loop through the user's view, checking it against the pre-defined one, until an inequality is found, in which case the method will return false.

My code is below. Inside the onCreate I have a buttonListener (when the user is ready to check answers)
            btnSolution.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(checkAnswer() == true){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "all good!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "no good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

the checkAnswer() method is then defined as follows

```
 public boolean checkAnswer() {
      final int ROW_COUNT = 15;
      final int COL_COUNT = 10;
      final String ROWS[] = {"R1","R2","R3","R4","R5","R6","R7","R8","R9","R10","R11","R12","R13","R14","R15"};
      final String COLS[] = {"C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","C10"};

      for(int i=0; i<ROW_COUNT; i++) {
          for(int j=0; j<COL_COUNT; j++) {
              String a = ROWS[i];
              String b = COLS[j];
              int editTextBaseId = getResources().getIdentifier("box" + a + b, "id", getPackageName());
              int editTextAnswerId = getResources().getIdentifier("boxA" + a + b, "id", getPackageName());
              EditText editTextBase = (EditText)findViewById(editTextBaseId);
              EditText editTextAnswer = (EditText)findViewById(editTextAnswerId);
              String textBase = editTextBase.getText().toString();
              String textAnswer = editTextAnswer.getText().toString();
              if(textBase.equals(textAnswer)) {
              }
              else {
                  return false;
              }               
          }
      }        
      return true;         
   }
```

Unfortunately when I try and run this I am getting a crash and the following error in my LogCat

```
12-17 00:05:02.075: E/SKIA(16370): FimgApiStretch:stretch failed
```

Any obvious errors?

Comment: why findViewById ? You get the view from onClick, if it's an edit text cast it. And that E/SKIA(16370): FimgApiStretch isn't an error; lookup to see where the crash happens, i bet it's a NPE

Comment: oh, this is pretty much what arcastro says :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an error itself. I guess you're using a Samsung as your target device, if so, don't worry about it.

In the other hand, maybe it's better to compare only the strings. All those findViewById are inneficient.

Looking at your code:

```
EditText editTextAnswer = (EditText)findViewById(editTextAnswerId);
```

Do you have both views in the same layout, and the one with the answers is hidden? I mean, if you have the view with blank editTexts as the content of your activity, you can't find the editText with the answer as it's in other xml (assuming you did it as a different xml).

Comment: Yes, sorry to clarify the answer is in another layout.